# VariableStatement semantics in ECMAScript

Tags: javascript

The production VariableStatement :

```
var VariableDeclarationList ;
```

is evaluated as follows:

1. Evaluate `VariableDeclarationList`.
2. Return `(normal, empty, empty)`.

I want to know about meaning of normal and empty.

Answer (score 7):

ECMAScript describes an internal type to explain the behavior of statements, it's called [The Completion Specification Type](http://www.ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.9).

Values of the Completion type are triples of the form of `(type, value, target)`, where:

- `type` can be `normal`, `break`, `continue`, `return`, or `throw`.
- `value` can be any language value or `empty`.
- `target` can be any `Identifier` or `empty`.

In the case of the `VariableStatement`, the returned completion has no observable effect, it is a *normal completion*, since the **flow of control** is not modified.

Other *statements* that return a *normal completion*, are e.g. an empty [`Block` statement](http://www.ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12.1), the [Empty Statement](http://www.ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12.3), the [ExpressionStatement](http://ecma262-5.com/els5_html.htm#Section_12.4), the [`debugger` statement](http://www.ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12.15) (when no debugger attached), etc...

A [`FunctionDeclaration`](http://ecma262-5.com/els5_html.htm#Section_13) (which is not a statement, but a [`SourceElement`](http://ecma262-5.com/els5_html.htm#Section_14)) also returns a `(normal, empty, empty)` completion, thats why for example:

```
eval("function f(){}"); // returns undefined
```

The [`eval` function](http://ecma262-5.com/els5_html.htm#Section_15.1.2.1) after executing the code, examines the completion result, and if the type is `normal` and the value is `empty`, it explicitly produces `undefined` (see step 7 of [`eval`](http://ecma262-5.com/els5_html.htm#Section_15.1.2.1)), whereas:

```
eval("(function f(){})"); // returns a function object
```

There the parentheses build a [`PrimaryExpression`](http://ecma262-5.com/els5_html.htm#Section_11.1), which is part of an [`ExpressionStatement`](http://ecma262-5.com/els5_html.htm#Section_12.4), and this statement returns the completion `(normal, GetValue(exprRef), empty)`, where `expRef` will be the value of the `FunctionExpression`.

If the completion `type` if other than `normal` is known also as an "**abrupt completion**".

For example:

```
function foo() {
  return 5;
}
foo();
```

The `return` statement inside `foo` will produce a completion that looks like `(return, 4, empty)`.

The `target` value in the triplet is only used by `break` and `continue`, to reference an identifier of a [`LabelledStatement`](http://ecma262-5.com/els5_html.htm#Section_12.12), e.g.:

```
foo: while(true) {
  while(true) {
    break foo;
  }
}
```

The completion result of the above `break` statement would be `(break, empty, foo)`, since the flow of control is transfered from within the second `while` to outside, at the level of the `foo` label.

You can see more details about how this internal type is used, on all other statements that perform *nonlocal* transfers of control as [`break`](http://ecma262-5.com/els5_html.htm#Section_12.8), [`continue`](http://ecma262-5.com/els5_html.htm#Section_12.7), [`return`](http://ecma262-5.com/els5_html.htm#Section_12.9) and [`throw`](http://ecma262-5.com/els5_html.htm#Section_12.13).